# How to disable printing of HHH90000014 in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I disable logging of:

```
WARN  org.hibernate.orm.deprecation - HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
```

I don't want to disable all `org.hibernate.orm.deprecation` but just this one HHH90000014.

Is it possible?

Comment: I doubt it is possible. If it all, you will be able to disable all, but not jsut this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what logging library you are using. I found this page which can help you using log filters: [logging-filters](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/filters.html)

Filter pseudo code:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        return "org.hibernate.orm.deprecation".equals(record.getSourceClassName()) 
            && record.getMessage().contains("HHH90000014") ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, I'm using log4j2 and it also has filtering so I'll go that route. Thanks.